# spark.read.csv... reading 367 files and creating only 12 partitions - WHY?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

#### The setup:

- I am using AWS EMR and reading data from S3 for a table data
- The table is represented with 367 files under one folder Each file <64MB
  (which is the default block size of S3)

#### What I think should happen:

When I read spark.read.csv... it should create a dataframe with 367 partitions. But that doesn't happen! It uses **367 tasks to read as expected**, **however creates a dataframe with only 12 partitions**!!

#### Here are the 367 tasks created when defining the dataframes using dataframe API:

```
val y_cdc = spark.read.csv("s3n..........")
```

[image]

#### Here is my code that confirm that 12 partitions are created:

```
y_cdc.rdd.toDebugString
```

[image]

#### RDD API works well:

[image]

Whats going on here?

Comment: Why do you think that `it should create a dataframe with 367 partitions` ? Was it mentioned somewhere in documentation?

Comment: Could you please mention what's the total size added up to for these 367 files?

Comment: @bhanu, total size of 367 files is around 3MBs.

Comment: @sarvesh, typically the no of partitions should be equal to the amount of parallelism possible, which I believe should be 367. this is confirmed when I use sc.textfile RDD API

Comment: @ALL, Why has someone rated the question a "-1" ! any explanation?

Answer (score -1):

- Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
  *
- @note This method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as
- all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.
  From the collect definition, so we can see that all the data will be loaded into the driver's memory. So the tasks will be reduced.